# Take a screenshot and terminate application in case of freeze-up during test execution via SpecFlow

Tags: specflow

I have automated UI tests. Right now our desktop application may freeze-up during test execution. This freeze is infinite.

What I want to do is to take a screenshot, put in SpecFlow report and terminate an application.

I know, that I can use the time for separate methods. And create an event handler which will monitor application state in a separate thread. But maybe the community has an easier solution.

Comment: As soon as your app hangs up you will be no longer to interact with it and your test should fail. Just add some actions on test failure (AfterScenario feature).

Comment: Unfortunately, timeouts and after scenario are not useful. Some of the modal windows block our application completely. And SpecFlow cannot reach AfterScenario.

We will write a handler to monitor application in a separate thread.